R how to create a new dataframe with column values calculated from three other dataframes
I'm new to R and struggling to create a new dataframe where the values for multiple columns are created using values from columns with the same names from three other dataframes with the same structure.
#Example data
country <- c('Australia')
animal <- c('koala')
state <- c('NSW')
df1 <- data.frame(country, animal, state, apples=2, oranges=4)
df2 <- data.frame(country, animal, state, apples=1, oranges=2)
df3<- data.frame(country, animal, state, apples=5, oranges=2)

I need to create new dataframe called df4 with one row and the same five columns as the dataframes above, and in df4 the value for apples = (apples value from df1 + apples values from df2)/apples value from df3
and the value for oranges uses the same calculation.
Desired output
country     animal   state   apples   oranges
Australia   koala    NSW     0.6      3    

Note I have about 50 other columns with other fruit names and I need to do the same calculation for all of them. I'd like to do the calculations all at once rather than having to name each fruit column one at a time.
dplyr code preferred but any suggestions would be much appreciated.
I've tried searching joining and merging but can't get the calculation to work across 50 variables at the same time.

I would just use base R for this kind of operation:
cols  <- names(df1)[sapply(df1, is.numeric)]
data.frame(
  country, animal, state,
  (df1[cols] + df2[cols]) / df3[cols]
)
#     country animal state apples oranges
# 1 Australia  koala   NSW    0.6       3


A dplyr/tidyr version:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1,df2,df3, .id="df") |>
  pivot_longer(-c(df, country, animal, state)) |>
  summarise(.by=c(country, animal, state, name),
            value=(value[df==1]+value[df==2])/value[df==3]) |>
  pivot_wider()


# A tibble: 1 × 5
  country   animal state apples oranges
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Australia koala  NSW      0.6       3


Edit:
Prior to dplyr version 1.1.0 (before summarise(.by=...)), we have to use group_by():
bind_rows(df1,df2,df3, .id="df") |>
  pivot_longer(-c(df, country, animal, state)) |>
  group_by(country, animal, state, name) |>
  summarise(value=(value[df==1]+value[df==2])/value[df==3],
            .groups='drop') |>
  pivot_wider()


# A tibble: 1 × 5
  country   animal state apples oranges
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Australia koala  NSW      0.6       3


Thank you! I can see what this is doing but when I apply it to my real data I get the following error. Any suggestions why?      "Error in summarise():
! Problem while recycling value = (value[df == 1] + value[df == 2])/value[df == 3].
✖ value must be size 324 or 1, not 27. ℹ An earlier column had size 324."     After the pivot longer part the df is 648 rows so the 324 must have something to do with that but no idea what it means.

What does your real data look like? Or how does it differ from the sample data you provided?

The dfs each have 8 observations, 31 cols. 3 cols are id cols (like country, animal, state) and the rest are the numeric cols I'm trying to do the calculation on. So after pivot longer and before trying to summarise the df is 648 rows and 6 cols.

Full error Error in summarise():
! Problem while recycling value = (value[df == 1] + value[df == 2])/value[df == 3].
✖ value must be size 324 or 1, not 27.
ℹ An earlier column had size 324.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: country= "", animal= "" (In "" are the values in the first group in the long df)

Using the example data provided by @mrguyperson and running your code above I get the error pasted below. This may be because my system has older versions of packages? (I can't update them)        Error in summarise():
! Problem while recycling value = (value[df == 1] + value[df == 2])/value[df == 3].
✖ value must be size 64 or 1, not 6.
ℹ An earlier column had size 64.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In value[df == 1] + value[df == 2] :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Which dplyr version are you using? packageVersion('dplyr')

See edit. I think this should work for you.

Yes the edit works! (I'm on dplyr version 1.0.10.) Thank you so much Edward

Phew! Glad it worked. :)  Don't forget to accept this answer. ;)

Here are a couple options using data.table and dplyr that could be helpful if you have multiple entries for country, animal, and state, and either those do not appear in the same order in each dataframe, and/or entries may not be shared by all dataframes. These options will also work even if your data are ordered and all dataframes contain matching ID rows, though SamR's option is probably faster in that case.
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Example data
country <- c('Australia', 'USA')
animal <- c('koala', 'wolf')
state <- c('NSW', 'Alaska')

df1 <- data.frame(country, animal, state, apples = c(2, 3), oranges = c(4, 1)) 
df2 <- data.frame(country = c(country, "USA"),  animal = c(animal, "beaver"), 
                 state = c(state, "Vermont"), apples = c(1, 1, 3), oranges = c(2, 8, 1))
df3 <- data.frame(country = c(country, "USA"), animal = c(animal, "beaver"), 
                 state = c(state, "Vermont"), apples = c(5, 2, 3), oranges=c(2, 2, 4))

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
dt3 <- as.data.table(df3)


dplyr option
bind_rows(df1,df2,df3, .id="id") |>
  reframe(across(where(is.numeric), ~(.x[id==1] + .x[id==2]) / .x[id==3]),
          .by = c(country, animal, state))


Output
    country animal  state apples oranges
1 Australia  koala    NSW    0.6     3.0
2       USA   wolf Alaska    2.0     4.5


pre v 1.1.0 dplyr
bind_rows(df1,df2,df3, .id="id") |>
  group_by(country, animal, state) |>
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~(.x[id==1] + .x[id==2]) / .x[id==3]),
          .groups = "drop")


Output
    country animal  state apples oranges
1 Australia  koala    NSW    0.6     3.0
2       USA   wolf Alaska    2.0     4.5


data.table option
dt4 <-rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2, dt3), idcol = TRUE) |> 
  setkeyv(c("country", "state", "animal"))

cols <- names(dt4)[!names(dt4) %in% c("country", "state", "animal", ".id")]

# make table of country, state, and animal combinations that are present in all DTs
all_present <- dt4[, .N, keyby = c("country", "state", "animal")][N==3][, N := NULL]

dt4[all_present, (.SD[.id == 1] + .SD[.id == 2]) / .SD[.id == 3], .SDcols = cols, by = .(country, animal, state)]


Output
     country animal  state apples oranges
      <char> <char> <char>  <num>   <num>
1: Australia  koala    NSW    0.6     3.0
2:       USA   wolf Alaska    2.0     4.5


Thank you so much! Actually, yes my real data has more rows and complexity so this is really helpful (and so simple). For anyone else who may use this: I got an error with the dplyr option "could not find function reframe". The solution was to change reframe to summarise because I must have an older version of dplyr.

I just noticed the dplyr option is deleting the state column if all rows have the same state value (this may happen in my data sometimes but not always). Is there a way to stop this happening? Also, in this line "reframe(across(where(is.numeric), ~(.x[id==1] + .x[id==2]) / .x[id==3])": is there a way to modify this line to apply one calculation where the value in dataset1 is.numeric and >=1 and a different calculation where the value is.numeric and <0? For example if the wolf apples value was -2.0 it gets a different calculation.

Can you provide example data where you lose the state column? I changed all the state values to the same in my example and don't see that result. Regarding the second part of your question, sure you can include an if_else statement like this:
bind_rows(df1,df2,df3, .id="id") |>   reframe(across(where(is.numeric), ~if_else(.x[id==1] >=1, (.x[id==1] + .x[id==2]) / .x[id==3], 0)), .by = c(country, animal, state))

The if-else statement is perfect. I used a different method to avoid losing the state column. Thank you for your help!
